# Искажение изображения в псевдо-3d приложении

Tags: c#, monogame

Я начал писать простое псевдо - 3d приложение. Чтобы избавиться от искажения - эффекта рыбьего глаза, я следую советам учебников из интернета. Таким образом вычисляется высота среза стены:

```
float corDist = dist * (float)Math.Cos(rayangle * Math.PI / 180);
float height = 1000 / corDist;
```

Когда я запустил приложение, я обрадовался тому, что стена имеет нормальную высоту

**(Это стена, хоть и не совсем хорошо её напоминает)**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоило мне немного повернуть камеру вбок, как увидел вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то при некоторых значениях угла стены искажаются, при других же значениях - выглядят как нужно.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы показали непонятную формулу и 2 скриншота. Вы думаете, что этого достаточно для понимания вашей проблемы? Приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: О, круглая стена, такого даже в думе не было!